# Next url in react

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

In Django I can do this:

```
    def my_function(request):
        next = request.GET.get('next')
        ....
            if next:
                return redirect(next)
            return redirect('home')
```

I'm new to react and this is what I'm trying to do exactly.
For example a user click to go to a page but had to login first, after login, how do I redirect to their intended page?

Here's what I try

```
    import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

    const Router = useHistory();

    let memoryToken = new InMemoryCache();

    const login = async ({ token, exp }, noRedirect) => {

    //This part is not important
        memoryToken.writeQuery({
            query: IS_LOGGED_IN,
            inMemoryToken: {
                token: token,
                expiry: exp,
            },
        });
        //THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
        if (!noRedirect) {
            Router.push("/");
        }else{
           //HOW DO I GET REDIRECT URL?
        }
    };



    const auth = async ({ token, exp }, noRedirect) => {
         .....
       //HOW DO I GET redirectUrl URL?
         login({ token, exp }, redirectUrl)
    };
```

After login, how do I redirectUrl to their intended page?

Answer (score 0):

In Django you do `redirect('home')`, in React you also do like `Router.push('/home')`

The redirectUrl you can get from your server, or just hard code.
Don't know if that answers your question.

Comment: How do I redirectUrl from the server?

Comment: How about hard code first? just write `if (!noRedirect) {Router.push("/");}else{Router.push("/home")}` and change from there